por que tengo el error en mi programa: error: 'm_f' does not name a type|
estoy realizando un programa en c++ en poo el cual tiene que calcular el área y perímetro de una figura y un triangulo pero en mi archivo de encabezado Programa en esta parte me sale este error
les proporciono el codigo del encabezado de programa.h:
#ifndef PROGRAMA_H_INCLUDED
#define PROGRAMA_H_INCLUDED

#include <iostream>    
#include "figura.h"    
#include "triangulo.h"

using namespace std;
class Programa {
  private: Figura *m_f;
  public: m_f = new Figura(val);
  m_f = new Triangulo(val, val1, val2);
  m_f = new Isoceles(val, val1);
  void PedirDatos() {
    int opc;
    cout << "Menu";
    cout << "1-.Figura";
    cout << "2-.Triangulo";
    cout << "Que figura quires calcular?";
    cin >> opc;
    switch (opc) {
    case 1:
      int val;
      cout << "elegiste figura";
      cout << "Proporciona los lados de la figura";
      cin >> val;
      MostrarResultado();
      break;
    }
  }
  void MostrarResultado() {
    cout << "el area y perimetro es:";
    cout << m_f->Area();
    cout << m_f->Perimetro();
  }
  void Run() {
    PedirDatos();
    MostrarResultado();
  }
};
#endif // PROGRAMA_H_INCLUDED


Las instrucciones no van sueltas dentro de una clase. Deberías asignar la variable m_f dentro del constructor u otra función de la clase.

en que parte en especifico tendría que modificarlo?? si se puede saber o que me falta complementar??

Esas 3 líneas en las que asignas la variable m_f. No entiendo qué quieres hacer, pero lo que hagas debe suceder dentro de una función. Ponlo en PedirDatos, el constructor o donde fuese conveniente.

Tu error es debido a la extraña manera que organizas el código que te oculta un error evidente:
class Programa {
  private: Figura *m_f;
  public: m_f = new Figura(val);
  …
};

Si lo organizamos de una manera más habitual:
class Programa
{
private:
    Figura *m_f; // Definición

public:
    m_f = new Figura(val); // Asignación
  …
};

Vemos que estás usando una asignación en un punto en que se espera una declaración.
// Esto es una asignación, no puede usarse en la definición de clase.
m_f = new Figura(val);

Probablemente querías hacer esto:
class Programa
{
private:
    Figura *m_f = new Figura(val); // 
    …
};

Pero tampoco te compilará, porque en el contexto de definición de clase no tienes variables, así que seguramente querías que ese código formase parte de una función, probablemente el constructor:
class Programa {
private:
    Figura *m_f;
public:
    Programa(int val, int val1, int val2)
    {
        m_f = new Figura(val);
        m_f = new Triangulo(val, val1, val2);
        m_f = new Isoceles(val, val1);
    }
    …
};

Pero aunque el programa ahora compile, es erróneo pues tienes fugas de memoria ya que pides memoria dinámica (new) y antes de dejar de sobrescribir el puntero que la contiene no llamas a delete, así no tendrías fugas de memoria:
class Programa {
private:
    Figura *m_f;
public:
    Programa(int val, int val1, int val2)
    {
        m_f = new Figura(val);
        delete m_f;

        m_f = new Triangulo(val, val1, val2);
        delete m_f;

        m_f = new Isoceles(val, val1);
    }
    …
};

Pero ahora tenemos un programa que compila pero no tiene sentido. Deberás pensarlo un poco mejor.

El formato de "private: Figura *m_f;" fue mi cupla.  Utilicé un formateador en línea, pero cuando vi que, SE no me dejaba arreglarlo.  El original estaba en dos líneas.
